# Java syntax for static and non-static methods

Tags: java, syntax, static

The syntax obj.call is used for a call to a non-static method in Java, where obj is a reference to a Java object, and call is a method call. Explain how Java’s type system limits what call may be for any value of obj.

I saw this in a text book and the answer they give does not really explain well, could someone explain it to me please?

**Edit:** 
The answer, which i do not understand

A reference to a Java object may be a variable, or it may be a method call. In either case,
it has a type: if it is a variable it has the declared type of the variable, if it is a method call
its type is the declared return type of that variable. The type may be a class type or an
interface type. Java’s type system limits what the method call on obj may be to methods
which are given in the type of obj. So call must be of the same name as a method in the
type of obj, must have the same number of arguments as there are method parameters,
and each argument must be compatible with its matching parameter. Compatible means
of the same type or a subtype. If this requirement is not met, there will be a compiler
error.

Comment: The question from the textbook is now quite clear to me. Could you please provide their answer?

Comment: What's the name of the book that you are reading?

Comment: Modern software development using Java.

Comment: Can you post the code example around which they have placed this explanation?

Comment: There was no sample code

Answer (score 1):

If `obj` is a variable representing an instance of any object, chaining it with a method name will cast it own method (non-static). Example :

```
Object obj = new Object();
obj.toString();//non-static call
```

To call a method statically, you need to put the class name before the method name. Example :

```
class SomeClass
{
    public static void aStaticMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("static method");
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SomeClass.aStaticMethod();//Static call.
    }
}
```

Note that if the static method is in the same class and you are in a static context, you can call it directly by calling it.

```
class SomeOtherClass
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SomeClass.aStaticMethod();//Static call.
        anotherStaticMethod();//Another static call.
    }

    public static void anotherStaticMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("Another static method");
    }
}
```